# AES-256-GCM transfer IV and AuthTag

Tags: man-in-the-middle, aes, initialisation-vector

Question is for transfer encrypted data between two services (Like HTTP, GRPC or etc...) Can I transfer `IV` and `AuthTag` in plain, Is this approach secure?

I have sample code in Node.js and I'm not crypto expert. See the code for more info:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

class AES {
  static encrypt(string, key) {
    const iv = Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(12), 'utf8');
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    let enc = cipher.update(string, 'utf8', 'base64');
    enc += cipher.final('base64');
    return [enc.toString('base64'), iv.toString('base64'), cipher.getAuthTag().toString('base64')].join('.');
  }

  static decrypt(encrypted, key) {
    const [encString, ivString, authTagString] = encrypted.split('.');
    const enc = Buffer.from(encString, 'base64');
    const iv = Buffer.from(ivString, 'base64');
    const authTag = Buffer.from(authTagString, 'base64');

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
    let str = decipher.update(enc, 'base64', 'utf8');
    str += decipher.final('utf8');
    return str;
  }
}

const phrase = 'Sample Text 1234';

// key store in secure place
const key = Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(32), 'utf8');

const encrypted = AES.encrypt(phrase, key);
console.log(encrypted) // pass encrypted data into network that include (IV and AuthTag)

// for another
const decrypted = AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
console.log(decrypted)
console.log(decrypted === phrase)
```

- Use case, transfer data between service that might work in public network
- Just a Secure key is shared between service nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the IV and the auth tag can be sent in plain.

The auth tag is a tag the recipient can use to verify that the message has not been altered. This is important because AES-GCM acts as a stream cipher and anyone could flip bits.

The IV is not a secret, the only thing to be concerned about is that it must not be reused with the same key.

I can however not comment on the code itself as I am not familiar with the library.